# Partial order given by a stratification on a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, order-theory

A (good) stratification of a topological $X$ is a partition $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ ($I$ finite) of $X$, with $X_i$ locally closed, such that $X_i \cap \overline{X_j}\neq \emptyset \Rightarrow X_i \subset \overline{X_j}$. It follows that each $\overline{X_i}$ is the union of some $X_j$. We define the relation $"i \leq j$ if and only if $X_i \subset \overline{X_j}"$ on $I$. Is this a partial order relation? In other words, does $i \leq j$ and $j \leq i$ imply $i=j$? I don't know why, i cannot see it.

Comment: $X=X_1=[0,1]$ and $X_2=(0,1)$ seems to be a counterexample, right?

Comment: @freakish Thank you. So i don't understand this https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09XY. He says that the relation i talked about is a partial order.

Comment: What is the definition of "locally closed" there? Is it typical, i.e. $A$ is locally closed if it is an intersection of an open and a closed subset? I ask because the defintion of "partition" already differs from the standard one (i.e. collection of pairwise disjoint subsets that sum to whole space).

Comment: @freakish I think yes. It is also the one i use usually.

Comment: @freakish in your example $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not disjoint.

Comment: @freakish In the example you gave, $\{X_i\}$ is not a **partition** of $X$.

Comment: Ah, right right. Interesting. Maybe it is true after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that if $X$ and $Y$ are (non-empty and) locally closed, and if $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, then it is impossible to have $X\subset \overline Y$ **and**  $Y\subset \overline X$.

Proof:

Write $X=O\cap C$ with $O$ open and $C$ closed.

Since $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ and $Y\subset \overline{X}$, it follows that $Y\subset \left(\overline{X}\setminus X\right)$. But $\left(\overline{X}\setminus X\right)\cap O=\emptyset$ (easy exercise), and so $$Y\cap O=\emptyset$$
Therefore it is impossible for any point in $O$ (and therefore in $X$) to lie in the boundary of $Y$.

Comment: As for the "Easy Exercise": if $x \in O \cap (\overline{X}\setminus X)$ then there exists an open neighborhood of $x$ all contained in $\overline{X}\setminus X$. By taking the complementary of this neighborhood in $\overline{X}\setminus X$, since $X$ is open in $\overline{X}$, we get a smaller closed set containing $X$ and this is a contradiction. Does it work? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: An other proof for the Easy exercise: if $x \in \bar X \cap O$, then it is the limit of a sequence $x_n \in X$. Since $X = O\cap C$ with $C$ closed, we see that the limit $x$ belongs to $C$. We have proved that $x \in X$. In other words, $ \bar X \cap O \subset X \cap O$.